# Accessing a remote mounted directory from Windows CMD.EXE

Tags: windows, windows-xp, script, batch

I have a remote directory that is shared and mounted to my localhost. I know the remote directory is mounted and shared correctly as I can read, write, execute the file during a normal mouse and click event.

Although, I do need to script something and would like to do this using the Windows cmd executable.

For example, I want to `cd`/ change directory into the the remote directory and rename the file.

How do I do so in a sample Windows script?

So far, the command line below isn't working for me. I might not be passing this properly in the first place.

```
C:\>cd \\myremotehost\MY_DIR
```

Error:

> `\myremotehost\MY_DIR'
>
> CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories

I want to script this and rename `myfile` to `mynewnamefile`.

Comment: The error message CMD gives you is very straightforward: "CMD does not support UNC paths". You need to map a drive to it so that CMD doesn't have to know that it's a UNC path.

Comment: Does it have to be with the UNC (\\myremotehost\MY_DIR), or do you care if it is mapped (given a drive letter)? Do you want a workaround?

Comment: it doesn't matter for the directory name. I was able to mount using a letter. as long as i can make my way to the files.

Comment: Duplicates [this ServerFault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/50085/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to mount the network location as a network drive before you can use it from the command prompt.  Like so:

```
net use x: \\myremotehost\MY_DIR
x:
```

Afterwards you should be able to perform whatever operations you want, using the X:\ in place of \myremotehost\MY_DIR.  When you are done, you can disconnect the drive with

```
net use x: /delete
```

Comment: You can also map the drive, x: in this case, from My Computer and it will work just the same in your script.

Comment: @Fopedush- got the mount working now. Thank you. I can see the files using `ls x:`

Answer (score 1):

Your share is probably mounted as a drive letter. You would most likely want to do something like this:

`ren X:\my file myfile`

To script it, you could simply put the command into a .cmd file.

Comment: That assumes that he maps it. Ren does not work with UNC names.

Comment: It does assume he maps it. He did say it was mounted, which could mean a few things in Windowsland.

Comment: @Kirk- thanks for your input. So far, I do have the mount now, thanks to Fopedush. Its "x:" . Although now I am trying to rename that file and getting `The syntax of the command is incorrect`. As for the obvious, I can see the files when i do `ls x:`  Thanks!

Comment: found it its `ren x:\my file newfile`. thanks guys!

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, then what you want to do is this batch file:

> x:
>
> cd\directory
>
> ren filename newfilename

The first command seems to be what you are missing.

Another workaround if you want to use the UNC is this:

> xcopy \\server\directory\filename
>   \\server\directory\newfilename
>
> del \\server\directory\filename

The effect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using 'net use' and map a drive letter and manually unmap it as it works on all versions of Windows.

However, it is good to know that `pushd` instead of `cd` will (depending on the version of Windows) map a drive letter for you automatically, but make sure to call `popd` to unmap the drive letter.

```
**pushd** \\server\directory\  
ren filename filenamenew
```